# A simple subprocess command (python 2.7) with "find" not working

Tags: python, subprocess

I do not see why my subprocess command (python 2.7) below does not work. Any idea? Thanks.

```
In [35]: import subprocess

In [36]: subprocess.call("for f in $(find  _test/  -name *.c -print); do echo hello; done ".split(),shell=True)
f: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
f: -c: line 0: `for'
Out[36]: 2
```

Comment: I've traced the error to the `.split()` section. If you remove that, the code runs. I suspect you'll have to run the find and generate the output, then move onto the processing.

Comment: There's no output in your loop except a single integer - success or fail - as far as the `.split()` is concerned. It's not reading stdout.

Comment: If it's of any use, I use glob2 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2) for recursive searches instead of calling out to subprocess, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the call to `.split()`; the shell will split your command for you, since you're using `shell=True`.

It's also worth noting that that command won't necessarily work as you expect it to. You should surround the glob with single quotes, so that it doesn't get expanded by the shell:

```sh
for f in $(find _test/ -name '*.c' -print); do echo hello; done
```

and if any of your filenames have spaces in them, this command will see them as separate files (e.g if you have a file called `foo bar.txt`, this loop will see two filenames, `foo` and `bar.txt`). It would be *much* safer to do whatever you're planning to do in Python rather than shelling out.